# Арифметическая последовательность

Tags: c#

Подскажите как реализовать в коде:

a + (a+r) + (a+r+r) + (a+r+r+r) + (a+r+r+r+r)

2 + (2+3) + (2+3+3) + (2+3+3+3) + (2+3+3+3+3) = 40

Comment: Реализовать что? Найти сумму? Или в цикле или по школьной формуле.

Comment: @MBo
реализовать в цикле

Comment: Очень хорошо. Читайте про циклы, реализуйте. Если что не получается - конкретные вопросы задавайте.

Comment: мда, просите конкретики, а вот это и есть задание. Вот представьте, что вам пришло точно такое же без доп пояснения, реализуйте. Про циклы ничего не сказано, тут просто сам понял, но не понимаю как реализовать данный цикл, решать за меня нужно, хотяб на мысль навести, а тут отправляют циклы читать. Лучшеб и не спрашивал

Comment: Так вас на мысль и навели - читайте про циклы. Хотите задать вопрос так, чтобы повысить шансы на ответ - читайте [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) раздел справки.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо, вопрос закрыт. Помогли разобраться на другом форуме, почему то там всё сразу поняли, подсказали формулу и по ней реализовал цикл без всякого чтения про циклы

Comment: @Partymaker копировать туда-сюда чужой код бесконечно не получится. Надо учиться писать свой. И здесь не форум, а база знаний.

Comment: @aepot хах, а где вы увидели копирование? Мне подсказали просто формулу, а реализовал цикл уже сам. И тут раздел называется вопросы, вопрос я и задал, читайте внимательней

Comment: Формулы для вычисления k-го члена арифм. прогрессии, и готовую формулу для вычисления  суммы без циклов проходят в 8-9 классе. Поэтому мы предположили, что вы пока не знаете про цикл for или что-то подобное.

Comment: Да даже тут вычислять нечего `a + r * i`, сложение перевести в умножение, арифметика, первый класс начальной школы. Мне даже в голову не пришло, что вы пытались с этим разобраться самостоятельно. Ничего этого в вопросе нет. И вам стоит внимательнее почитать правила сайта.

Comment: _Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу._ - это вам цитата на будущее.

Comment: @aepot интересный вы человек. Сперва упрекаете в копировании кода которого не было, затем, что я не знаю математику первого класса :) Я новичок в c#, могу чего то не помнить или не знать из математики, поэтому и обратился сюда что бы помогли разобраться. Вам в свою очередь если нечего ответить по теме, то просто пройдите мимо, вы же сами говорите тут база знаний, а занимаетесь упрёками. Дальше разговор закрыл, правила сайта учту.

Comment: @Partymaker не к чему мне вас упрекать. Я говорю только о фактах, которые вижу, хорошо это или плохо, упрекать себя или не упрекать - решать вам. `копировании кода которого не было` - а с кодом из ответа вы что сделали? Ну это так, к слову.

Comment: @aepot  вы в очередной раз подтверждаете, что мне с вами не о чем разговаривать, и то, что читаете не внимательно. Я выше ответил, что мне подсказали формулу на другом форуме и я закрыл вопрос, после чего человек скинул сюда решение и подписал - "Хоть вопрос фактически не закрыт, пусть ответ останется на всякий :D"

Comment: Вы перепутали этот сайт с фриланс-биржей. В остальном все нормально. Здесь не принято решать задачи за вас, здесь принято помогать вам с решением, которое вы выполняете сами, но столкнулись с трудностями и пришли сюда. Так понятнее?

Comment: @aepot а где я просил решать за меня? Может я не совсем корректно составил вопрос, но есть C#, есть условие и есть цикл. Я думаю этого достаточно для опытных разработчиков подсказать и навести на мысль, что и сделал человек на другом ресурсе, без упрёка на то, что я не знаю математику за первый класс. Я вам ещё раз говорю, пройдите просто мимо, не создавайте мнения "отзывчивого" коммьюнити.

Comment: Нормально здесь все с коммьюнити. Все что надо, я уже сообщил. Дальше самиирешайте, стоит здесь еще вопросы создавать или нет. Такие как этот, возможно не стоит.

Comment: может с коммьюнити и нормально всё, но точно не к вам относится. Если и создам вопрос, то надеюсь именно вы пройдёте мимо, так как уже показали насколько готовы "помочь".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int a = 2, r = 2, n = 5, sum = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            sum += a + (a + r * i);
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
}
```

Результат 40 при n = 5 (Как раз по Вашему примеру). Хоть вопрос фактически не закрыт, пусть ответ останется на всякий :D

Comment: благодарю ;) именно так :)